# How to load second UITableViewCell at the bottom of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` which populates custom UITableViewCells which I call "`TopCell`". Everything works flawlessly. However, I would like to add a second custom UITableViewCell to be displayed at the bottom of the `tableView`. Lets call it "`BottomCell`"

I already created `BottomCell` and connected to its custom class. Just like I did with the "`TopCell`"

Bottom cell will displayed only once and at the bottom of the `tableView`.

Here below is the basic code for `TopCell`. So how to integrate `BottomCell`?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TopCell", for: indexPath) as? TopCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let topVal = indexPath.row + 1
    let noVal = myData[indexPath.row].no ?? 0

    cell.configureCell(top: topVal, no: noVal)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count+1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == myData.count {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BottomCell", for: indexPath) as? BottomCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        return cell
    }
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TopCell", for: indexPath) as? TopCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let topVal = indexPath.row + 1
    let noVal = myData[indexPath.row].no ?? 0

    cell.configureCell(top: topVal, no: noVal)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I did not realize it was that simple.